# Display content in Repeater

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I must have done so that I can print anything into my Repeater, but it is such that I can not really for it to write the content that I really want to do.

I have written the code like this

forum.aspx

```
<asp:Repeater ID="RepeaterKommentar" runat="server">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <div class="kommentarBox">
                        <%--print content here--%>
                    </div>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:Repeater>
```

forum.aspx.cs

```
var UsersKommentar = from KommentarA in db.forumkommentars
                         join BrugereA in db.brugeres on KommentarA.brugerid equals BrugereA.Id
                         where KommentarA.forumid == getid
                         orderby KommentarA.Id descending
                         select new
                         {
                             UserName = BrugereA.fornavn + " " + BrugereA.efternavn
                         };

    RepeaterKommentar.DataSource = UsersKommentar;
    RepeaterKommentar.DataBind();
```

*The problem, is I'm not entirely sure how to access the `object` of `Enumerable` through my data source.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what data exist within your `object`, but you've bound it to the repeater and called data bind.  So all you need to do now is call:

```
<%# Eval("...") %>
```

The `...` would represent the name of the column, or property.

Comment: lol!!... I think I have tried everything, but then it was just that .. but thanks for your help !, Hope you will give me a +1 for questions